# Is SIGINT intrinsically unreliable in python?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, generator, sigint, keyboardinterrupt

I have an application that relies on `SIGINT` for a graceful shutdown. I noticed that every once in awhile it just keeps running. The cause turned out to be a generator in `xml/etree/ElementTree.py`.

If `SIGINT` arrives while that generator is being cleaned up, all exceptions are ignored (recall that default action for `SIGINT` is to raise a KeyboardInterrupt). That's not unique to this particular generator, or to generators in general.

**From the python docs:**

> "Due to the precarious circumstances under which `__del__()` methods are invoked, exceptions that occur during their execution are ignored, and a warning is printed to sys.stderr instead"

In over five years of programming in python, this is the first time I run into this issue.

If garbage collection can occur at any point, then `SIGINT` can also theoretically be ignored at any point, and I can't ever rely on it. Is that correct? Have I just been lucky this whole time?

Or is it something about this particular package and this particular generator?

Comment: (for reference: [documentation page from which the quote is taken from](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__))

Comment: This is just a guess, but the problem doesn't happen with built-in types or types that doesn't define `__del__` in Python. Also you can do something with `signal.signal` to handle it some other ways.